# How to define the stack address range in C for embedded systems

Tags: c, gcc, embedded, stm32

I am working with a legacy code.
So I am not sure about where to define the start and stop address for stack.
The environment specifications are.

OS        : Free RTOS
Compiler  : Gcc compiler
Processor : STM32

This is to understand the start and stop address
of stack to experiment on the maximum stack range used on a particular run.

Comment: [uxTaskGetStackHighWaterMark](http://www.freertos.org/uxTaskGetStackHighWaterMark.html) will return the number of unused words on a particular task's stack when the task was at a maximum. Would that work for what you're trying to do?

Comment: When a new thread is created with the function sys_thread_new() in Free Rtos, it allocates a pool of stack addresses to that thread(task). But to write a known value as you are telling we need to know the starting address of the same. This stands as a point of confusion

Comment: Okay. When I read the question I thought that by wanting to understand the maximum stack range used, you wanted to know _how much_ of the stack is used. But you want to know _where_ the stack is used so that if you write to a specific address, you can ensure it won't get clobbered by a stack. I'm not sure of how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In FreeRTOS, you don't provide the stack explicitly, you merely specify the requred size and `xTaskCreate()` dynamically allocates the stack for you.

FreeRTOS does have some support for [stack usage and overflow checking](http://www.freertos.org/Stacks-and-stack-overflow-checking.html).